# SQL Server aggregator

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql

I am learning SQL, and I am trying to solve a problem in SQL Server -- what we use at school. I am however playing around with Postgres because it's the only DB I can easily install at home. I know this may cause difficulties, but I imagine my query is quite easy.

Having said that, in Postgres I create the following sample table:

```
WITH Test(id1, id2, rank, value) AS 
( VALUES
  (57462, 7800,  2, 0.789),
  (66353, 15384, 1, 0.123),
  (66353, 44861, 2, 0.456)
)

select * from Test
```

I'd like the SQL Server query which let me pick out the 1st and 2nd row -- I want them because for every id1, I want the row with the minimal rank. I've played around with subqueries and/or aggregators (which my friend says is available in Postgres but not SQL Server), but am still generally stuck. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Partitioning" or "windowing" methods are available in MSSQL.

Great tutorial over at [simple talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/)

Windowing methods, like `OVER` would create data like your example.

[`RANK`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) is one of the methods that you would use to build your rank.

Now as for querying out of your current result set, you might just do:

```
select id1, min(rank)
from test
group by id1
```

With a bit more information about your original data, I think creating a windowing method would be very simple, and accomplish your objective with one query instead of two.

As a side note, having worked with both PostgreSQL and MSSQL for years, I think its safe to say that you will not find anything in Postgres you cannot do in MSSQL. Might just take thinking about your problem in a different way.

EDIT:

I notice you're using the `WITH` syntax to create your postgres table.  MSSQL also has [Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that work very nicely w/ windowing methods.

If you want to limit to just those rows as you note in the comments you'd might want something that identifies that as an unique record like its own id field.

```
WITH Test(id, id1, id2, rank, value) AS 
( VALUES
  (1, 57462, 7800,  2, 0.789),
  (2, 66353, 15384, 1, 0.123),
  (3, 66353, 44861, 2, 0.456)
)
```

For that matter you could join on the items directly and forget adding an id column:

```
select *
from TEST t
where exists 
    (select 1
     from test tt 
     where t.id1 = tt.id1 and t.rank = min(rank
     group by id1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. How do I get the rest of the columns then? I need to read off id2 and value as well. Writing this into a subquery and then joining on Test seems to bring me back to 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a rank column, the easiest should be to do the following:

```
Select id1
    , Min(rank) as Min_Rank

From Test

Group by id1
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) at home to try to test your queries.
It's good to test queries against many RDBMS.

But I suggest you to try some kind of Lite or Express SQL edition since
the ANSI SQL only cover a very basic set of tools and for sure more complicated
working queries you made for one RDBMS ill fail for other.

BTW almost anything available to Postgres ill,at least, get a equivalent at MSSQL.

For your specific query try using [RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176102.aspx)